# Write to another application's internal memory

Tags: android

I have 2 applications with different package names. E.g. App1 and App2.

App1 needs to write some files to App2's internal memory so that it could be uploaded to the backend.

I have used the following in App1 to do so:

```
filePath = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("app2.package.name", 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;
```

I can get the correct path but could not write to it. I checked the logcat, it is showing "Permission denied".

Am I missing something? What's else needs to be done?

Comment: You need to implement a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Answer (score 0):

I used android:sharedUserId in the Android manifest and now is able to write across the app's internal memory.

As my only purpose is to write text files (no sharing etc is involved), I found this the most easiest to implement.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access another applications internal memory directly. Only with root access on your device you could do so.

But why should your app write to another app's memory? If you have to do some communication between 2 apps there are other ways to do so. i.e. use a service, content provider or broadcast an intent and recieve it with your other app.

Comment: You could let one App implement a Content Provider and enable access to its data to other Apps

Comment: This is how you modify contacts and Images on the phone memory

Comment: Sure but you cannot access another application's internal memory directly.

Comment: You can access images on the Android Gallery App (which implements a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#ClientProvider)) and you can delete images and add new ones. This is the same as accessing its memory. You may not be able to get it through folders & paths (I think that is what you mean), but you can access the content that the provider is providing with the right permissions, and this is what he needs